# Tailor forced casts conflicts

Tags: ios, swift

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

It's standard sentence that implements the table view's cell's properties. But Tailor (it's a Swift analyzer/linter) warns about you shouldn't forced the CustomTableViewCell as `as!` If I used to as `as?`, I have to implement cell's properties as `cell!`. But Tailor don't warn about **[forced-type-cast] Force casts should be avoided**. What's the reason of this? How can I implement cell's without unwrap of cell as `cell!` What's the correct programming paradigms for forced casts operations in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with "Tailor" but most likely the reason it is giving you this warning is because if a force cast fails then obviously your program will crash and thats never good.

The `as!` operator does have its place if you are 100% sure that what you are casting is of that type. But, even then its better to be safe than sorry and you should use a `guard` or `if let` statement instead in order to handle a failed cast.

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell {
  //do what you like with cell
}
```

or

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
  //abort current scope, return, break, etc. from scope.
}
//do what you like with cast cell
```

Comment: Well, how can I return the tableviewcell without return the cell. In if statement there is no cell declaration for tableview functions to return cell.

Comment: @mathema im not exactly sure what you mean in your comment, but if youre referring to the body of the guard statement what i wrote is just generic comment about guard statements you are correct you will still need to return the correct type from the function! sorry i admit that it rather ambiguous - ill make an edit!